# How to solve java.lang.NullPointerException error in button click event?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, testng, xpath

I'm using Java,Selenium web driver and TestNG framework. I have a method to click a button in web page. But it didn't work. When debugging I could find xpath is not passed to the button. Then I tried giving xpath in the same place where click event is called using driver.findElement(By.xpath.....). It worked without any error. I have included my codes below. Please check and help me to solve this problem.

```
ClickNewButton();      

// Method body   
public void ClickNewButton() {click(NewButton);}       

@FindBy(xpath = Locators.newButton)  // In this place newButton has it's xpath
WebElement NewButton;  // Here NewButtton doesn't contain any xpath. It's null (This is where problem occurs exactly)

// Xpath in Locators class
public static final String newButton = "html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/button";               



// click method's body in Base class
public void click(WebElement webElement) {
    webElement.click();
}
```

> Please note that first three code segments are in same class and that class is extended from Base class

Comment: please share your html file

Comment: @sameer, I don't think that it's possible. But I can confirm there is nothing wrong with the xpath. I've tested it.

Comment: Did you try with some wait time?

Comment: give xpath like below and try `@FindBy(xpath = "your xpath")
private WebElement btnSubmit;`

Comment: I guess you are talking about a scenario of element is not found. If it's so , I didn't use wait but I have tried sleep method to wait until the interface loads properly. Seems to be that's not the problem

Comment: @sachintha I tried what you said. It doesn't work too.

Comment: Locators.TWQ_newButton or Locators.newButton ?

Comment: I've edited it now. This error occurred while I was inserting the code in here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76945/discussion-between-sachintha-and-joe).

Comment: Show us how you initiate elements on your page.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to the problem. I just had to add single line of code to make this work.

```
MyClass object= PageFactory.initElements(driver, MyClass.class);
```

I had to add this code to the class where I was creating the test and tried. It worked. The Error wasn't in using of **@FindBy**. So I guess this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavascriptExecutor -

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", yourLoginButton);
```

Comment: Why do you think this is going to solve `Null Pointer Exception`? The question is about solving the NPE and not how you can achieve this using other method.

Answer (score 0):

I think the line which is causing the problem may be

```
@FindBy(xpath = Locators.newButton)
```

You are directly calling an element from the `Locators` class, right?

Try creating an object of `Locators` class in the Class where you are using the `@FindBy`.

I may not be correct because the flow that you are given in the question is not enough for finding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
package org.com;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;

public class ASOS {
    
    WebDriver driver;
    
    
     @Test()
     public void login() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Raja\\eclipse-workspace\\FebrevisionTask\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/ref=nav_logo");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
       // driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement txtUserName=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/deals?ref_=nav_cs_gb']"));
        txtUserName.click();
         
     }

    
   @Test()
   public void TodayDealsPage() throws InterruptedException {
       
       
       Thread.sleep(2000);
       
//     JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
//     executor.executeScript("window.scroll(0,450)","");
       
       JavascriptExecutor js1 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
       js1.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, 450)",""); 
       
       Thread.sleep(3000);
       
       WebElement laptop = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Top Offers on Laptops & Desktops; Upto INR 40000 Off']"));
       laptop.click();
       
       
   }
       
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to the community! It would be helpful to add an explanation to your code on how this solves the problem.